# Reusing angularjs components from a big project

Tags: angularjs

I have a bunch of code that is written in angular js and seems well structured. I need to take a controller out and its respective html but I notice it has lots of dependencies on other services which I would understand here that I need those too.

Which is straight forward, but it seems that it is also reliant on code from other controllers and such, so I am stuck as how to take out what I need while leaving the rest behind.

Some guidance would be helpful and let me know what more info you may need.

Comment: I don't think there's any silver bullet when trying to extract code that is heavily reliant on other code in a project. This isn't necessarily specific to Angular, either. If the up front design is not to build a modular solution then you'll have a lot of work refactoring it as you are finding now.

Comment: Agree to the above comment. Perhaps ask us if you have a specific question about angular? Or perhaps something that you've seen and are not sure how to isolate...